# How to exclude words from txt file?

Tags: windows, text

For example, i have text like this.

> blahblabhalha'important1'jiojif
>   blahblabhdsasalha'important2'jiojisdsdf
>   blahblabaaahalha'important3'jiosaajif

After using a program I want to get important1important2important3

Which program should I use?

Comment: Can you form your question exactly what you need help with, for example i'd like to parse a string of text and return all chars between opening and closing single quotes. If this is your question, many text editors have this option, notepad++ being one, or using a simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken notepad ++ has an option for that

Comment: Do you know which option could it be ? I can't find it